# Custom notification with togglebutton

Tags: android, notifications, custom-component, toggleswitch

In my app I created a very simple notification. I'm trying, without success, to customize the notification by inserting a togglebutton that allows me to activate and deactivate a service performed at startup. I would also like to display an icon in the notification that changes depending on the status of the service (started or stopped). Does anyone have an example of code?